# PHP array order issue, order by years, months and days

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array generated by an script, it has years as key holding various months, which hold days. My problem is the order. This is one array generated:

```
  {
    "1970": {
        "1": {
            "1": {
                "id": 291,
                "cliente_id": 16,
                "texto": "Maria del Pilar rexistrouse na plataforma, xa se pode facer contacto co usuario por medio da plataforma.",
                "tipo": "Rexistro na plataforma",
                "icono": "flag-checkered",
                "color": "primary",
                "fecha": "0000-00-00",
                "estado": "evento"
            }
        }
    },
    "2015": {
        "12": {
            "3": {
                "estado": "falta",
                "texto": "A pesar de estar anotado na acci\u00f3n <span style='font-style: italic;'>INICIACI\u00d3N AO COACHING<\/span>, non se presentou ou non asistiu as horas m\u00ednimas para superala",
                "tipo": "Faltou a unha acci\u00f3n",
                "icono": "exclamation",
                "color": "danger",
                "fecha": "2015-12-03"
            },
            "21": {
                "id": 2108,
                "cliente_id": 16,
                "texto": "assfghndfgndfgn",
                "tipo": "Onbasdf",
                "icono": "phone",
                "color": "midnightblue",
                "fecha": "2015-12-21",
                "estado": "evento"
            }
        }
    },
    "2016": {
        "1": {
            "31": {
                "estado": "asistencia",
                "texto": "Asistiu e completou satisfactoriamente a acci\u00f3n: <span style='font-style: italic;'>HIXIENE ALIMENTARIA - MANIPULADOR\/A DE ALIMENTOS<\/span>.",
                "tipo": "Asistiu a unha acci\u00f3n",
                "icono": "star",
                "color": "success",
                "fecha": "2016-01-31"
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "16": {
                "estado": "asistencia",
                "texto": "Asistiu e completou satisfactoriamente a acci\u00f3n: <span style='font-style: italic;'>Prueba Adagal<\/span>.",
                "tipo": "Asistiu a unha acci\u00f3n",
                "icono": "star",
                "color": "success",
                "fecha": "2016-03-16"
            }
        },
        "7": {
            "26": {
                "id": 2095,
                "cliente_id": 16,
                "texto": "asdfasdfasdf",
                "tipo": "asdfasdf",
                "icono": "thumb-tack",
                "color": "midnightblue",
                "fecha": "2016-07-26",
                "estado": "evento"
            }
        },
        "8": {
            "21": {
                "id": 2107,
                "cliente_id": 16,
                "texto": "Prueba agosto",
                "tipo": "Prueba agosto 2016",
                "icono": "phone",
                "color": "midnightblue",
                "fecha": "2016-08-21",
                "estado": "evento"
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "3": {
                "estado": "falta",
                "texto": "A pesar de estar anotado na acci\u00f3n <span style='font-style: italic;'>INFORM\u00c1TICA E NOVAS TECNOLOX\u00cdAS <\/span>, non se presentou ou non asistiu as horas m\u00ednimas para superala",
                "tipo": "Faltou a unha acci\u00f3n",
                "icono": "exclamation",
                "color": "danger",
                "fecha": "2016-06-03"
            },
            "6": {
                "estado": "falta",
                "texto": "A pesar de estar anotado na acci\u00f3n <span style='font-style: italic;'>INFORM\u00c1TICA E NOVAS TECNOLOX\u00cdAS <\/span>, non se presentou ou non asistiu as horas m\u00ednimas para superala",
                "tipo": "Faltou a unha acci\u00f3n",
                "icono": "exclamation",
                "color": "danger",
                "fecha": "2016-06-06"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the generator which takes the data from the database:

```
$aux_time = array("eventos"=>$cliente->eventos,"asistencias"=>$cliente->accionesAsistidas,"faltas"=>$cliente->accionesNoAsistidas);
      foreach ($aux_time["eventos"] as $evento) {
        $evento['estado'] = 'evento';
        $final[intval(Date("Y", strtotime($evento->fecha)))][intval(Date("n", strtotime($evento->fecha)))][intval(Date("j", strtotime($evento->fecha)))] = $evento;
      }
      foreach ($aux_time["asistencias"] as $accion) {
        $aux_evento = array();
        $aux_evento['estado'] = "asistencia";
        //exclamation
        $aux_evento['texto'] = "Asistiu e completou satisfactoriamente a acción: <span style='font-style: italic;'>$accion->nombre</span>.";
        $aux_evento['tipo'] = "Asistiu a unha acción";
        $aux_evento['icono'] = "star";
        $aux_evento['color'] = "success";
        $aux_evento['fecha'] = $accion->fecha_fin;
        $final[intval(Date("Y", strtotime($accion->fecha_fin)))][intval(Date("n", strtotime($accion->fecha_fin)))][intval(Date("j", strtotime($accion->fecha_fin)))] = $aux_evento;
      }
      foreach ($aux_time["faltas"] as $accion) {
        $aux_evento = array();
        $aux_evento['estado'] = "falta";
        $aux_evento['texto'] = "A pesar de estar anotado na acción <span style='font-style: italic;'>$accion->nombre</span>, non se presentou ou non asistiu as horas mínimas para superala";
        $aux_evento['tipo'] = "Faltou a unha acción";
        $aux_evento['icono'] = "exclamation";
        $aux_evento['color'] = "danger";
        $aux_evento['fecha'] = $accion->fecha_fin;
        $final[intval(Date("Y", strtotime($accion->fecha_fin)))][intval(Date("n", strtotime($accion->fecha_fin)))][intval(Date("j", strtotime($accion->fecha_fin)))] = $aux_evento;
      }
```

I dont set an associative array, only insert month multiarrays in certain numeric key.

Why year 2016 has the month order 1, 3, 7, 8, 6?? When I want to print the array in the frontend I cannot order it using PHP functions like sort, ksort, array_multisort, or anyone of them. Even I used the intval() function in order to force that keys where numeric. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you not change the initial query to set the sort order correctly? You havn't shown the original sql so it's hard to know if you have tried that already

Comment: The problem begins on the first of the PHP script `$aux_time = array("eventos"=>$cliente->eventos,"asistencias"=>$cliente->accionesAsistidas,"faltas"=>$cliente->accionesNoAsistidas);` which makes an associative array from 3 different data sources. That data sources are mixed in the array `$aux_time` which is the one I have to sort. I tried sorting each data source but is obvious that I got same result.